# 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: npm

I am learning react and my favorite statement is 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command. I am literally sick of and tired of listening this statement. What the heck is the problem.

Every next day when i try to run my react app. The app doesn't work so i try to make a new one and when i run the commands it gives me 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command. Then i have to spend 30 minutes daily on this problem. I have literally tried 10-15 solutions and some of them work. But why do i have to face this problem daily. It's been a week.

Comment: Yes npm is already installed on my machine. And my OS is Windows 10.

Comment: I haven't faced this problem this many times when i was working in VueJs.

Comment: in the next 30 minutes i try the same old solutions which i had tried on the first day. My colleague said it must be your path issue. But my paths are already set. If it's because of path issue why do i have to set it daily.

Comment: Please outline **exactly** what you do in that 30 minutes every day.

Comment: Go through the same old solution on Stackoverflow and Github. Delete and add the paths again. Re-install node. Sometimes restart. Run the react commands. Which also takes time

Answer (score 0):

Looks like npm is not installed globally or might be deleted for some reasons. Please go through https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm to properly install npm. Also please check if you have link npm properly.

Also do you have added node js as PATH in environmental variable? like: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\"

Comment: Please remove your current version of node js and reinstall latest node version form https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: I reinstalled node, set the paths again and restarted my laptop. After reboot i opened cmd and typed node -v it showed me the version of currently installed node and then i typed npm install npm@latest -g it showed npm is not recognized and then i typed node -v again to check and it showed me node is not recognized.

Comment: Please open command prompt with admin then check if it is working fine or not?